# If $T$ is a $k$-tensor and $S$ is an $l$-tensor, then $\text{Alt}(T \otimes S) = (-1)^{kl} \text{Alt}(S \otimes T)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors

Could someone please help me with the following algebra question?  I know it should be easy, but the textbook leaves the proof to the reader and I am having a hard time with it. Thank you in advance.

> Let $T$ be a $k$-tensor and $S$ be an $l$-tensor.  Then show that $\text{Alt}(T \otimes S) = (-1)^{kl} \text{Alt}(S \otimes T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T = v_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_k$ and $S = w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_l$ be $k$- and $l$-tensors, respectively.  Then
$$
\text{Alt}(T \otimes S) = (v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k) \wedge (w_1 \wedge \dots \wedge w_l) = (-1)^c (w_1 \wedge \dots \wedge w_l) \wedge (v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k) = (-1)^c \text{Alt}(S \otimes T),
$$
where $c$ is the number of swaps of adjacent tensors needed to bring about the given change in the ordering.  This can be achieved by moving $w_1, \dots, w_k$ successively to the left.  Each of those $k$ vectors must be moved $l$ spots to the left (to pass each of the $v_i$'s), so $c = kl$, proving the result.

Example ($k = l = 3$):
$$
v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3 \wedge w_1 \wedge w_2 \wedge w_3 = - w_1 \wedge v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3 \wedge w_2 \wedge w_3 = w_1 \wedge w_2 \wedge v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3 \wedge w_3 = - w_1 \wedge w_2 \wedge w_3 \wedge v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3.
$$